# HTTPS error in wordpress site hosted in AWS ECS fargate container [SOLVED]

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to host WordPress site in ECS Fargate along with RDS.

This is how I install Wordpress in ECS Fargate.

1. ECS cluster - task - WordPress installed
2. rds - MySQL - connect WordPress
3. for this step: the WordPress site is up and running - http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx (with IP address)
4. For the next step, I would like to change HTTP to https, then I installed SSL to ALB:
5. Application load balancer set up and added target group pointing to the private IP of my WordPress ECS. (Ref : [redirect http to https](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/))
   [image: listener in load balancer]

   This is the target group from which the load balancer forwards
   [image]
6. alrdy added A record of pointing to that load balancer in route 53.
   Till this, the site is still running with HTTP status.

> ***All are running under the same VPC, security group.***

Then, I changed the URL and Site URL settings with ***HTTPS*** in WordPress's admin dashboard, and then the site is completely down and can't access anymore. I got this error when I'm trying to access the URL both HTTPS and HTTP: `502: Bad Gateway’

---

> UPDATE: I modified the wordpress docker image by adding some lines
>   related to SSL force and used it in ECS container as base image.
>   Then,the https is ok now.

---

Comment: Can you check what the redirects are trying to do? It sounds like its in a redirect loop possibly between 2 domains

Comment: I edited the question back by adding the listener settings, please check again

Comment: How does the target group config look for the 443 listener?

Comment: no, this is the application load balancer's listener settings

Comment: Yes I mean, what do the target group settings look like. Are you forwarding to HTTP? I am guessing that the site url should probably be using http rather than https as the application is loaded via HTTP in the container.

Comment: Are you forwarding to HTTP? mean the target groups settings must be HTTPS:443? 
currently my target group is using HTTP:80

Comment: Ok. I created new target group with HTTPS:443 and added Ip addr of ecs. But this time the error is changed : 502 Bad gateway showing

Comment: Yeah thats because the container would need to be running https within it

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is [documented by Wordpress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/administration-over-ssl/#using-a-reverse-proxy), as the ALB will being provided as if its a proxy.

Unfortunately the change appears to require a change to the `wp-config.php` file.

The suggested fix to add this following code snippet to the file so that your Wordpress does not get caught in this redirect loop.

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
$_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

This updates the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` value if the `X-Forwarded-Proto` is set to HTTPS. This will be set via the Load Balancer.

Comment: yes, but I am using ecs container which I can't have access to config file.

Comment: I understand, unfortunately the problem is that your site is getting caught in a redirect loop because the site URL is using https, but the container is running http. In the backend it keeps attempting to redirect you and hence gets caught in a loop. The alternative is update to http in the backend, however some URLs might be broken.

Comment: So i can’t change to https if I hosted wordpress in ecs?